# Using for loop to create matrix from vector?

Tags: matlab

I have a simple question on using for loop to create a matrix from a vector for example

```
A = [1:101]; 

matrix = [1   2   3   4  ... 50;
          51  52  53  54 ... 100;
          101 1   2   4  ... 49;
          50  51  52  53 ... 100]
```

Could anybody please show me how to do it? Thanks a lot

Comment: How does `matrix` relate to `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming in addition to `A` you also have the number of rows and the number of columns of `matrix` as inputs i.e.

```
A = 1:101;
nRows = 4;
nCols = 50;
```

The try this:

```
% initialize
matrix = zeros(nCols, nRows); % create it transposed because we'll have to transpose it later because MATLAB is column-major

%figure out how many times we will have to repeat A
nRepeat = ceil(numel(matrix)/numel(A));

% Tile A
A_tiled = repmat(A, 1, nRepeat);

%fill in matrix
matrix(1:end) = A_tiled(1:numel(matrix));

%Finally, transpose
matrix = matrix';
```

which returns

```
matrix = [1   2   3   4  ... 50;
          51  52  53  54 ... 100;
          101 1   2   4  ... 49;
          50  51  52  53 ... 99]
```

which is as close as possible

Comment: Yes, exactly that I want.
Thanks a lot Dan :)

Comment: @user3727281 next time please attempt the problem yourself first before you ask on SO and post code of your attempt if you can't solve it. Also, your question was very vague, next time please include a description of what you'e trying to do. It's not easy to just work it out from the numbers and it's just lucky that I saw the pattern you were after.

Comment: @user3727281 Also don't forget to accept this answer if it has solved your problem...

Comment: Dear Dan,
How can I accept this answer that if it has solved? Please let me know.

Comment: @user3727281 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be using a loop?

```
A= [1 2 3 4 ... 1000];
numberOfColumns = 3;
[matrix,padded] = vec2mat(A,numberOfColumns)
```

Output:

```
  1       2        3
  .       .        .
 998     999     1000
```

Comment: Yes, by using a loop. But your example has some values are equal to zero. From the zero value, I want to reset the loop to create. Do you have any idea? Thanks a lot.